# Error: Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I am new to flutter and am trying to fix an issue with an app that I inherited.
I was able to build and run this app and then something changed. Not sure what, but I keep getting this error when I run the app in debug mode.

The full error is: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module

From what I can tell from googling around is that it appears that I have the wrong Java version.
However, I have tried several different Java versions and I still get the same error.

Here are the specifics.

OS: Windows 11
IDE: Andriod Studio Giraffe - 2022.3.1
Flutter version: 2.10.5
Java Versions I have tried:
Eclipse Temurin version 1.8.0_382
Oracle OpenJDK version 11
JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.6

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
        compileSdkVersion = 32
        targetSdkVersion = 32
        minSdkVersion = 23
        appCompatVersion = "1.4.1"
        playServicesLocationVersion = "19.0.1"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // [required] flutter_background_geolocation
            url "${project(':flutter_background_geolocation').projectDir}/libs"
        }
        maven {
            // [required] background_fetch
            url "${project(':background_fetch').projectDir}/libs"
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app\build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new Exception("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

Project background_geolocation = project(':flutter_background_geolocation')

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply from: "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/background_geolocation.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.integragroup.deliverytrack.mobile"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('../Signing/Integra')
            storePassword "f1dalg0"
            keyAlias "Integra"
            keyPassword "f1dalg0"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles "${background_geolocation.projectDir}/proguard-rules.pro"
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.0'
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to build with differen Java versions:
Eclipse Temurin version 1.8.0_382
Oracle OpenJDK version 11
JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.6

I tried to build with Gradle 4.1.3

Also tried building with gradle-7.3-all.zip

Answer (score 1):

step 1 File->Project Structure...
[image]

setp 2  select jdk1.8
[image]